# Can you change preset html form input value?

Tags: html, input, forms

So if I have a form with a text input, or a select input, I want that box to have a certain value when the page loads.  I know you can add,

```
value="pre defined value"
```

but when the user erases that and puts in something else, when the form is submitted, is the value that is sent the predefined one or the one that the user changed it to?

Comment: What happens when you test this?

Comment: @David I don't know. the page that i need to use it on could really mess stuff up if something i dont expect happens.

Comment: *"or a select input"*: you can't erase that (well, we can with many devtools but my parents can't)

Comment: *the page could mess stuff up* > Then reduce your problem and try with a simplified page/code that only does that

Answer (score 0):

**The answer to your question is:**
The value that is sent is the input that the user typed into the textbox and the value from the select input will be the one you set unless the user uses his browser to change the value(with any developer tools).

**On a side note:**
If an attacker changes the values then that value will be sent, this is why you must validate all input on server side, and also validate input from hidden, select, checkboxes, etc... elements. Client-side validation is only helpfull to tell the user if he has filled an input with the wrong thing but won't help you against any attacks since they can change the values that are sent with developer tools or a proxy.